# Angular2 template Print variable value without binding it

Tags: angular2-template

i'm trying to print a variable value without binding it with the binding syntax {{}}, because in my case i'm having an editable input and a second input of the default value, each time i edit the input the defaut value input change also with the syntax :

```
 <tr>
     <td>description</td>
     <td contenteditable='true' (input)="onRowClick($event, 'description', i)">{{ row.description }}</td>
     <td>{{row.description}}</td>  <<==== default value must not change when editing the first one 
        </tr>
```

So i need in the case of the default value input just print the value without binding it